# :after on a absolutely positioned div

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to have an :after element for an element that is absolutely positioned?

This is my div and it is absolutely positioned:

```
<div id="myDiv" class="box">..</div>

.box
{
  width: 60px;
  height: 240px;
  position:absolute;  
  background:#333;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}
```

I want to add a vignette effect to the above div, so I have this:

```
.vignette:after{
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 85px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    -moz-box-shadow:    inset 0px 0px 85px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    box-shadow:         inset 0px 0px 85px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);

    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
    content: "";
}
```

However this works only if I add:

```
.vignette
{
  position:relative;
}
```

The problem is the vignette class is added to myDiv, so it overrides the absolute positioning (which I need for myDiv).

Any way I can add the same vignette effect, even if myDiv is kept absolutely positioned?

Comment: I made a fiddle of this and it works just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/pavloschris/v7CXw/  Are there other elements into `myDiv`?

Comment: Thanks.  You seem to be right.  There must be something else going on.  Let me close my question.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible with `absolute` positioned div, if you change `top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;` to `top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;` in `.vignette:after` style definition.

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't seem to do it. It vignettes the whole page.

Comment: Does your `.vignette` have `position: absolute`?